# Deleting specific data from multiple Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to clear data from multiple sheets. I have a code that works for the current active sheet and data ranges I need, but I can not for the life of me figure out how to make it clear the same data from multiple sheets. Here is the code:

```
// This section adds the top menu
   function onOpen() {
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Reset')
      .addItem("Formulas Only", "ResetFormulas")
      .addItem("Entire Page", "ResetPage")
      .addToUi()
}

// This section makes a button to reset the whole page copies the entire page
   function ResetPage() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data1');  // Enter tab name of what you’re copying from
     sheet.getRange('A1:U39').copyTo(ss.getRange('A1:U39')) //enter entire tab range

}
// This section copies only the cells you specify
   function ResetFormulas() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet12'); // Enter tab name here of what you’re copying 
from
//Header
  sheet.getRange('B6:E20').copyTo(ss.getRange('B6:E20')) //first range you’re copying
  sheet.getRange('N6:Q20').copyTo(ss.getRange('N6:Q20')) //next range
  sheet.getRange('B25:E39').copyTo(ss.getRange('B25:E39')) //etc
  sheet.getRange('N25:Q39').copyTo(ss.getRange('N25:Q39')) //you get it

 }
```

What specifically would I change to make it clear multiple sheets rather than the active one?

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between your script in your question and your goal of `I am trying to clear data from multiple sheets.`?

Comment: So I am building a pricing sheet. It will be the same exact sheet for every tab I end up having 5-10 tabs. That current script I am only using for the clear formulas function part of it. It currently clears designated cells on my active sheet. What i want is that code to clear data from the same exact designated cells on every tab at the same time not just the current active tab.

Comment: I do not see any code that "clears" data. Maybe what you mean y clearing is overwriting the data with the request `sheet.getRange('A1:U39').copyTo(ss.getRange('A1:U39'))`? If so, please see my answer below.

Comment: Correct! Sorry yeah it does not clear but copies from another sheet. By using the code below, the 'Data1' is where it copies from, but by setting the other sheets via "sheet2" "sheet3", doesn't that just copy from those as well? I guess what I am asking is what sets my sheet that it will copy from and where do I list the ones I want to clear? I did attempt the code below but it still only clear my first sheet and no others.

Comment: I figured it out... at least a way that accomplishes what I am after.  Anyone else looking to do the same thing here is the code that did it.

Answer (score 0):

- The line `sheet.getRange('A1:U39').copyTo(ss.getRange('A1:U39'))` specifies that data shall be copied to the range `'A1:U39'` in the active spreadsheet
- It doe not specify in which sheet the range is located, this is why Apps Script assumes that you want to copy into the active sheet
- If you want to chose instead a different sheet - you need to specify the sheet

**Sample:**

```js
   function ResetPage() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data1');  // Enter tab name of what you’re copying from
     var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Data2');  // Enter tab name of what you’re copying from
     sheet.getRange('A1:U39').copyTo(sheet2.getRange('A1:U39')) //enter entire tab range
  }
```